How to use a Web Worker bundled in an NPM package in a NextJS application
Github Repo to reproduce issue: https://github.com/kyledecot/next-worker-bug
I have a NextJS application and an NPM package. The NPM package is bundled using webpack/ts-loader and contains a web Worker & WorkerComponent.
I want to npm install this from npmjs in my NextJS application and use the worker via:
<App>
  <WorkerComponent />
</App>

This currently doesn't work however because I'm getting:
../worker/lib/index.js (1:1323) @ eval
 ⨯ Error: Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser
    at eval (../worker/lib/index.js:51:27)
    at eval (../worker/lib/index.js:53:11)
    at eval (../worker/lib/index.js:67:7)
    at eval (../worker/lib/index.js:3:32)
    at eval (../worker/lib/index.js:5:2)
    at (ssr)/../worker/lib/index.js (/Users/tabulous-xyz/Desktop/example/app/.next/server/app/page.js:173:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/tabulous-xyz/Desktop/example/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (./src/app/page.tsx:7:64)
    at (ssr)/./src/app/page.tsx (/Users/tabulous-xyz/Desktop/example/app/.next/server/app/page.js:162:1)
    at Object.__webpack_require__ [as require] (/Users/tabulous-xyz/Desktop/example/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
digest: "3559072519"


I'm unsure if this is a bug w/ NextJS, Webpack, or something else.

Do you have control over npm library? I've managed to find a working solution, which requires editing Worker component and webpack config. If it's a third party library, it would help to clarify exactly which library you're trying to use with Next.js

Yes I have control over both libraries!

workerize-loader is a specialized tool designed to handle Web Worker bundling.
So, I suggest using this approach to bundle your web worker within your Next.js application. This method effectively addresses the common issue of "Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser" that arises when using Web Workers in Next.js.
Please follow the below steps to implement this solution.
Step 1: Create the Web Worker in your NPM package (example: my-worker.js)
self.onmessage = function (e) {
  // Your worker code here
  self.postMessage('Worker response');
};


Step 2: Install the workerize-loader package:
npm install --save-dev workerize-loader

Step 3: Modify next.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /my-worker\.js$/,
        use: { loader: 'workerize-loader' },
      });
    }
    return config;
  },
};


Step 4: Use the Web Worker in your Next.js component:
import Worker from 'my-npm-package/my-worker.js';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const worker = new Worker();

  worker.onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log('Message from worker:', event.data);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    worker.postMessage('Hello, worker!');
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Run Worker</button>;
};

export default MyComponent;


